# How to replace an state without mutating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mutation

I am using React and Redux and i need to update my state with updated data. My state contains an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "messages": [/*somedata*/],
        "users": [/*somedata*/],
        "avatar": "/*somedata*/",
        "_id": "/*somedata*/",
        "type": "/*somedata*/",
        "createdAt": "/*somedata*/",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "messages": [/*somedata*/],
        "users": [/*somedata*/],
        "avatar": "/*somedata*/",
        "_id": "/*somedata*/",
        "type": "/*somedata*/",
        "createdAt": "/*somedata*/",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

So in this reducer, **i just want to replace or update the entire state array with my payload but without mutate my state**. My payload also contains the same array of objects as above but with updated data.

```
const chatsReducer = (state = chats, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case '@updateChats':
        return state = payload //i need something like this but without mutating
    default:
        return state
  }
}
```

Comment: how about `return {...payload}` ?

Comment: You can replace the state with the payload directly `return payload;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you, it creates a new array and populates it with all the objects within your `payload` array.

```
const chatsReducer = (state=chats, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case '@updateChats':
        return [ ...payload ];

    default:
        return [ ...state ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I need. Thank you.